Creating a Dataset for Fine tuning LLM using PEFT and SFT Trainer?
I have a dataset of 1000 records with 3 columns "question" ,"step by step answer"," single word answer" in CSV format. I tried to fine tune an LLM (gemma) on this dataset using SFTTrainer from TRL package. I am unable to understand how to organize and load this data so that it can be passed as a parameter to SFTTraining(). It would be helpful if you could mention how to process and pass it as input.
